# C++ : for loop in a switch case

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

i'm working on C++. i would like to know is there any possible way to use for loop inside a switch case? i tried to execute the code shown below (something like this but in detail and proper manner) but i don't see the loop in case c. any ideas on how to solve? your help is much appreciated. thank you very much. :)

```
switch (alphabets) 
{
    case a:
        //execute this code
        break;

    case b:
        //execute this code
        break;

    case c: 
        for (int c= 0; c >=200; c++)
            //execute this code
            break;

    default:
        break; 
}
```

Comment: That pseudo-code, when properly filled out, seems as if it should work. I'd suggest using braces for your case blocks though: `case c: { /* ... some lines of code ...*/  break; }`

Comment: You can not define variables into switch. Use `int c;` before switch, or use `for`(`int c`) in `{}` breakets.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c <= 200`?

Comment: @nick_n_a, we can do that in C++.

Comment: @BoBTFish  thank you but when i compile it is saying that c cannot appear in a constant-expression, although i have declared the int c in the beginning of the code and used braces.

Comment: @pritha Please show your real code then, so we can try to compile it.

Comment: Are `a`, `b` and `c` const variables defined elsewhere, or are they meant to represent characters? If so, they should be in single quotes: `case 'a':` The error you mention in your comment above is because you have declared `c` as a non-const int, and then tried to say `case c:` which is invalid because C++ requires that case value expressions be constants.

Answer (score 1):

General answer: there is no problem in having a loop in a switch case.  Only thing to notice is that a `break` in the loop will stop the loop but stay in the case. Also notice that switch cases with lots of logic in becomes less readable. See [basic example of for loop in switch case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8292861a410ce98e).

Specific answer: declaring variables in a switch case works best when using braces and avoid reusing names (c in this case) because even if it compiles, it is still a source of confusion.  About your specific code (which I assume is pseudo code), the for-body only contains a `break` statement, so it will just declare c and then fall through to default.